# In magento 2 what is "form_code" for customer address attribute to show on checkout step?

Tags: magento2, customer-attribute, customer-address

In magento 2 what is "form_code" for customer address attribute to show on checkout step?

I know in magento 2 form_codes are used to show customer address attributes on the customer registration, address book, manage customer address from admin and checkout step.

For customer registration we use form_code "customer_register_address", for address book we use form_code "customer_address_edit", for manage customer address from admin we use form_code "adminhtml_customer_address".

But I did not found any form_code code used to show customer address attribute on checkout step. What is "form_code" for customer address attribute to show on checkout step?

Answer (score 0):

There is only above mentioned three `form_code` we have to play with customer's addresses. Can you check once `customer_address`?. I think it can be a `form_code` work for you. Not Sure!

Comment: "customer_address" not working.

Comment: Okay PB,  Let me check. If I can help you more.

Answer (score 0):

`customer_register_address` is `form_code` for customer address attribute to show on checkout step.
 You can find in `Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor function getAddressAttributes()`